# Facebook PHP SDK: User ID on iframe page tab

Tags: php, facebook

I'm on my own page, I'm admin and I'm already "like" this peage, but this code:

```
require_once "api/facebook.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => APP_ID,
    'secret' => SECRET,
    'cookie' => true
));

$signedrequest = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
```

gives me just this data:

```
### USER ID ###

0

### SIGNED REQUEST ###

Array
(
    [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
    [issued_at] => 1330166798
    [page] => Array
        (
            [id] => 304887859549216
            [liked] => 1
            [admin] => 1
        )

    [user] => Array
        (
            [country] => us
            [locale] => en_US
            [age] => Array
                (
                    [min] => 21
                )
        )
)
```

So, getUser() = 0 and user id from signed request - empty.
What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

By default the "user" is the page, this way you can display content from your app relevant to the page. To determine who the user is, you can go through the standard backend redirects you would go through as if the user came to your app with no session/expired token. But you need to remember what page your were on since Facebook only passes that information on initial iframe load.

For a better user experience, I would use the Facebook javascript SDK. You can check everything in javascript and determine who the user is without performing any redirects. You can even prompt for authorization without reloading the page. If the user already had authorized your app, they see no changes and get no prompts, but you now have a "session" with that user and know their ID in javascript.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: So, no chance to get User Id without login/permissions? Even if im an page admin, page owner, author of app tab and already like this page?

Answer (score 0):

For getUser you need to log in in your application , show te login/permission dialog

Comment: So, no chance to get User Id without login/permissions? What about my own id, as admin of the page and author of this app?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this you can't currently get everything in the javascript SDK. It doesn't give you any of the user or page (for page tab) data which PHP SDK does.